# Android toString method in static context

Tags: android, tostring

So far i've been writing my Android app just by typing names in to methods. I am now sorting this out, going through and putting these into string.xml instead and referencing the string using:

```
txt.setText(this.getString(R.string.string_name));
```

However, when trying to use this in a static context (in public static void), it does not work and gives an error.

Does anyone have any pointers of how to overcome this? I am fairly new to Java/Android programming and this is the first time I have come across this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Extra code:

```
public static void ShowCatAddedAlert(Context con)
{
AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
builder.setTitle("Add new Category");
builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
DialogListner listner=new DialogListner();
builder.setMessage("Category Added successfully");
builder.setPositiveButton("ok", listner);

AlertDialog diag=builder.create();
diag.show();
```

}

Comment: Show your complete code please.

Comment: +1 for showing more of the code.  In your current line, you can't call `getString()` or reference the `TextView` that's probably an instance variable from a static context.  We'll need more context to help solve the real problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, all added now  - this is in my Toasts class.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `txt` is a `TextView`, then you can just do `txt.setText(R.string.string_name)`. You can usually reference to a string by it's resource id rather than getting it explicitly. More on that http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: If you're in a situation where you *can't* use the id outright, try this:

`myString=con.getString(R.string.string_name);`

Answer (score 1):

String resources, as all resources, are resolved from the application from a Context instance (usually that's an Activity instance or the Application instance).  In a static context, you don't have any instances unless you pass them in to your static methods.

One way or another, you need to do something in a non static context.  Either you keep a copy of the Resources object around and pass it to your static methods, or you pass a Context instance around that is capable of resolving your resources, or you have a static Resources object that gets set at some point before your static methods get called.

That being said, you might want to revisit whether or not you absolutely need these methods to be static.